# iPhone app on iPad: First screen does not adapt to iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I´ve tried running my iOS (for iPhone) game built with cocos2d on an iPad and almost everything works just fine, except the first screen to display where the UI elements is all over the place.

However, if I switch to another View (or Scene in Cocos2d) everything looks great and if I switch back to the previously messed up screen, it also looks normal.

So, the first screen to load when running on the iPad will look messed up and I have no idea what´s causing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: typically this happens when the first scene is initialized too early, before the app has learned of the device's actual orientation (apps always start in portrait)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks for replying. Do you got a suggestion for resolving this? My app is portrait only

Comment: Not without seeing the startup code of your app, when and where you create the director/ccview and the first scene.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when you inherit your scene class from `CCNode`. Change the parent class of your scene to `CCScene`.